# C# - How to retrieve data from Sybase SQL Anywhere 11?

Tags: c#, sqlanywhere

```
Platform: visual Studio 2010
Language: C#
Framework: .NET 4.0
Project: Windows Form
```

So, I am unable to retrieve data yet I'm already connected.
I've also tried to connect by using **'Server Explorer'**, and It could connect and retrieve data properly without any problem.

**Settings on 'Server Explorer'**

```
Connection String: Driver={SQL Anywhere 11};userid=*****;servername=*****;autostop=YES;integrated=NO;filedsn=C:\*****\*****.db.dsn;commlinks='SharedMemory,TCPIP{host=}';compress=NO

Provider: `.NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC`
```

Now, in my source code, I am using System.Data.Odbc;

```
Code:

String connString = @"Driver={SQL Anywhere 11};userid=*****;servername=gamca;autostop=YES;integrated=NO;filedsn=C:\*****\*****.db.dsn;debug=NO;disablemultirowfetch=NO;commlinks='SharedMemory,TCPIP{host=}';compress=NO;password=*****";
OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection(connString);
commandString = "DELETE from AGENCY";
try {
   using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(commandString, myConnection)) {
   myConnection.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   myConnection.Close();
}
```

Error: `Error [42S02] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Table 'AGENCY' not found`

I've also tried using OleDb and iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere (V2), but no luck, I can't pass through this one error.

Anyone has experienced the same problem?

Any comment is appreciated, Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

This Query runs on Default database (e.g. Master)
Add database name to your ConnString or CommandString as follow:

```
commandString = "USE MyDatabase DELETE from AGENCY";
```

Dont forget to replace MyDatabase with your Database name.

Comment: I added "dsn=MyDatabase" into my connString, but still same error occured. I also tried "USE MyDatabase DELETE from AGENCY" into my commandString, and it produced new error says "Syntax Error near DELETE line 1"